# iOS popover with a close button outside

Tags: ios, popover

I need to create below thing

[image]

Currently i'm using WYPopover , but I can't create the button since it's outside of the popover. Is there any existing solution out there ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Popover-controller's are exclusively used in iPad. If you want to use in iPhone, you should create it in a custom way.

I am not familiar with the XYPopover in Github, but normally the custom created popover should be dismissed whenever the user taps any place in the screen. That is one of the key feature of the popovers.

Normally the custom popovers are build like, adding a hidden parent view and then the visible image of a popover frame on it.

You should to do the following,

1. Avoid dismissing the parent view on tap of parent-hidden-view.
2. Add a close button at the area where you want to show the close button, on top of the parent-hidden-view.
3. Capture the button click and dismiss the view (remove the view from superview)

How to customize your need
Creating custom popover view is not a big task. It will take maxim one day, try it your self.

1. One Parent view with clear color
2. One background image of a popover frame.
3. View-inside popover (this needs to be customized for UIPopover also).
4. Close button.

Comment: thanks for the answer, your suggestion is quite similar to the guy above.  Basically I will have to implement a new library for this right ? That's hell lot of work especially when this project is kinda rushing

Comment: added more details, how to customize

Answer (score 0):

Create a bigger popover UIView holding all your child elements (current popover + button) and make its background transparent or however you wish.

Comment: to do it this way i think it's very very difficult to position the button correctly so that it lays just on top of the opening button, since i'm using autolayout ? or there's another magic trick ?

Comment: When you show the popover, get the "center" (x,y) position property of the underlaying opening button, pass it to your popover button and present the view.